# Resize server succeed but not applied

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I would like to resize the server via [this](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=resize-server-resize-action-detail#resize-server-resize-action) api. It returns `202` but the flavor is not applied. Its status is not changed to `VERIFY_RESIZE`.
The status is `Active`. I also tried it with `SHUTOFF` status. The same thing has happened via `CLI` and `horizon`.

When I tried to `confirm` the resize via [this](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=#confirm-resized-server-confirmresize-action), it does not work as the status is not `VERIFY_RESIZE`.

Comment: VERIFY_RESIZE is an asynchronous condition. The API returns, but it will take a while until the instance is resized. The process may fail, too. See also the definition of [return code 202](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202).

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks for your reply. I wait for it but It is not changed at all.